# Overlay Div on a Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to overlay an embed on top of another embed, and I am having some difficulties doing it, I am wondering how would I overlay one embed on top of another one.

Is there a way to do is purely using Bootstrap ?

This is my code for my embeds:

```
<div id="thePdfContainer" class="text-center">           
    <embed src="www.example.com/pdf1.pdf" width="550" height="800" type='application/pdf' id="thePdf">
    <embed src="www.example.com/pdf2.pdf" width="550" height="800" type='application/pdf' id="thePdf2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without Bootstrap

```
<div id="thePdfContainer" class="text-center">           
    <embed src="www.example.com/pdf1.pdf" width="550" height="800" type='application/pdf' id="thePdf">
    <embed src="www.example.com/pdf2.pdf" width="550" height="800" type='application/pdf' id="thePdf2">
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#thePdf{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    z-index:1;
}

#thePdf2{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

remember the highest z-index will always be on top.
set your positions top,left accordingly.

Comment: This breaks the centering of my div. I need it to be centered.

Comment: do you want both the pdfs in the centre of the div overlapping?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it

Answer (score 0):

Use `Z-index` to prioritize.

```
    #thepdf{  
      z-index:2;
    }
    #thePdf2{
      z-index:3
    }
```

so now the `#thePdf2` will be top of the `thePdf`, this will work for `div` and sorry i have not used `embed`.